# Scala map only right value and display error for left

Tags: scala, either

I have a sequence of left and right values like:

```
val l: Seq[Either[Error, Data]] = Seq(Left(Error), Right(Data), ...)
```

I want to map all `Right` values and display the error for a `Left`.
I have tried:

```
val data: Seq[Data] = l.flatMap {
  case Right(data) => data
  case Left(err)   => println(err) // doesn't work because println is Unit
}
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Don't try to do two many things at the same time, use `partitionMap` to separate the list into two, and then use a `foreach` with the list of errors to print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, just need to let `flatMap()` remove the `Error` after it's been printed.

```
val data: Seq[Data] = l.flatMap {
  case Right(data) => Some(data)
  case Left(err)   => println(err); None
}
```

A single traversal is all that's needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not a great practice to mix side effects and pure code like this, but something like (assuming a strict `Seq`):

```scala
def rightsAfterEffectingLefts[A, B](eithers: Seq[Either[A, B]])(effect: A => Unit): Seq[B] = {
  eithers.foreach(_.left.foreach(effect))
  eithers.flatMap(_.toOption)
}

val data = rightsAfterEffectingLefts(l)(println _)
```

It's possible to optimize to avoid the double iteration, though you'd likely want to approach different `Seq` implementations differently.

EDIT: after Luis's suggestion

```scala
def rightsAfterEffectingLefts[A, B](eithers: Seq[Either[A, B]])(effect: A => Unit): Seq[B] = {
  val (lefts, rights) = eithers.partition(_.isLeft)
  lefts.foreach(_.left.foreach(effect))
  rights.flatMap(_.toOption)
}
```

is an alternative definition.  It still double iterates and will likely be slower.

Comment: Is better to use `eithers.partitionMap(identity)` :)

Comment: Yeah, since the scaladoc window I had open was 2.12, I was in a 2.12 state of mind :)